# Angular + Django Backend. How to Log in base on user types in Django

Tags: django, angular

I'm facing a problem on how to integrate user permission like if the `is_superuser` is False, then log in to Author component and if `is_superuser` is True, log in to Admin component in Angular. I hope someone can help.

What I want,

1. 1. If the `is_superuser` is True in django, then log in to a Admin
      component / admin dashboard
2. 2. If the `is_superuser` is False in django, then log in to a Author
      component / Author dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyAuthToken(auth_views.ObtainAuthToken):
    serializer_class = MyAuthTokenSerializer
    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(MyAuthToken, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        token = Token.objects.get(key=response.data['token'])
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=token.user_id)
        users = json.dumps(UserSerializer(user).data)
        id = json.loads(users)["id"]
        email = json.loads(users)["email"]
        is_superuser = json.loads(users)["is_superuser"]

        return Response({'id': id, 'email': email, 'is_superuser': is_superuser, 
'token': token.key})
```

finally solved my own problem. What I did was return a json response which will include the some user details to the front end. then call it on the front end.
Here's how I did it in my front end. I console log it to check the results

```
interface TokenObj {
  id: number
  email: string
  is_superuser: boolean;
  token: string;
}

  _id: number;
  _email: string;
  _is_superuser: boolean;
  _token: any;
  mrToken: string;
  loginUser() {
    this.service.userLogin(this.authForm.value).subscribe(
      (result: TokenObj) => {
        this._token = this.cookieService.set('mr-token', result.token);
        this._id = result.id
        this._email = result.email
        this._is_superuser = result.is_superuser
        this._token = result.token
        console.log("******** id " + this._id);
        console.log("******** email " + this._email);
        console.log("******** is_superuser " + this._is_superuser);
        console.log("******** token " + this._token);   
        if (this._is_superuser === true && this._token){
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/approuting');
          }
        else if (this._is_superuser === false && this._token){
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/approuting/employee');
          }    
      },
      error => console.log(alert("wrong credentials"))
    );
  }
}
```

I really wanted to post my answer so I created a new account. I hope the other account can post answers soon. I also hope this will find beginner programmers who like me that is integrating angular and Django for a web development